# How can I run GUI emacs (using a shortcut) in a very light xmonad installation?

Tags: linux

I am trying to launch Emacs through a keyboard shortcut on my Debian/xmonad system. Relevant lines from my `xmonad.hs`:

```
~$ cat .xmonad/xmonad.hs
import XMonad

...

main =
  xmonad =<< xmobar
  (defaultConfig {modMask = mod4Mask, terminal="gnome-terminal"}
   `additionalKeysP`
   [ ("M-e", spawn "emacs"),
     ...
   ])
...

~$ xmonad --recompile
~$
```

(and even restart, I'm just proving minimal sanity here)

When I use the keyboard shortcut, nothing happens and if I inspect my `.xsession-errors` I can see:

```
~$ tail -n1 .xsession-errors 
emacs: standard input is not a tty
```

If I just start Emacs from the terminal I go in "terminal mode".

Finally:

```
~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

How can I further debug this?

---

Further version info:

```
$ apt-cache policy emacs
emacs:
  Installed: 46.1
  Candidate: 46.1
  Version table:
 *** 46.1 995
        995 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
[...]
$ apt-cache policy emacs-nox
emacs-nox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 46.1
  Version table:
     46.1 995
        995 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
[...]
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

Comment: Has Emacs been compiled with GUI support? How did you install it?

Comment: Is this an Emacs problem or an `xmonad` problem?  If the latter, we might want to migrate you to the Linux and Unix sister site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @phils This is Emacs version 46.1 from the Debian repositories.

Comment: @Dan I had posted the question on both unix and super user stackexchanges, got no comments in more than 10 days on either site except for the suggestion to try it out here (and couldn't be migrated cause it was already migrated once).

Comment: @jhc Sure, but you may want to consider flagging it for migration instead. In either case see my previous comment, too.

Comment: aronisstav: I've no idea what version 46.1 means (Emacs 25 is in pre-release right now), but if it's a debian package then I *suspect* you've only installed the emacs-nox (I think it's called) package. 'nox' being 'No X support'.

Comment: @phils Good guess, but no, I haven't, as you can see in the version info I have added to my question.

Comment: Have you tried `emacs -Q`? If you've got a properly installed emacs, running the command `emacs` should start the GUI version. It looks like you do have the GUI version installed, so the fact that it is opening in 'terminal mode' suggests that maybe there's something in your config that's explicitly requesting the non-GUI version. Maybe :/

Comment: The Debian package emacs is a meta package, so we still don't actually know which emacs you have installed. You can lookup the variables `system-configuration-options`  and `system-configuration-features` to see how your emacs was build. Just in case, try `type emacs` to see which emacs binary gets called.

Comment: What if you try: `("M-e", spawn "emacs < /dev/tty")` or whatever the appropriate way would be to write this in XMonad?

Comment: Many of these comments could also work as actual answers to "how I can debug this further", mind you! :)

Comment: @Tyler `emacs -Q` starts Emacs with a different colour scheme, but still no GUI.

Comment: @YoungFrog `type emacs` returns `emacs is hashed (/usr/bin/emacs)`. The `system-configuration-options`, when viewed from the console version has a `--with-x=no`, but I think that's reasonable (it's the console version after all).

Comment: @wvxvw Running this from a gnome-terminal takes me to the console version. Running it from the gmrun topbar does nothing.

Comment: @aronisstav AFAIK It is a configuration option set when building Emacs, so you really seem to have a nox version of Emacs.  Write a wrapper to start Emacs within a term emulator or install a GUI Emacs.

Comment: Setting Emacs' input explicitly to `/dev/tty` was meant to get rid of the `.xsession-errors` message (though not necessarily to eliminate the problem altogether). Do you still get the "input is not a tty" error after you've done that, or is it a different error? Mind you that I don't know what is the correct way to set input for XMonad version of invoking a command, maybe you need to look up its docs to figure out why it's not doing that / what should be done to do that.

Comment: @YoungFrog Indeed! On another machine the console version reports `--with-x=yes`. Let's see what I can do further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a solution with the help of some comments, so here's an answer:

@YoungFrog suggested I check the value of `system-configuration-options` (with `C-h v`) which revealed that the Emacs version I was running was configured with the `--with-x=no` option. This is a global setting, not related to the fact that I was reading the variable from the console.

This prompted me to try and reinstall the package, and I found out that @phils was right all along, as it turns out I had `emacs24-nox` (but not the metapackage `emacs-nox`) installed. Why was this one preferred over the plain `emacs24` eludes me... Removing `emacs24-nox` automatically selected `emacs24` and the problem was resolved.